# Return map results as keyed dictionary

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

In Python 2.7 have a dictionary with large `numpy` matrices, keyed with the name of the matrix:

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import numpy as np
names = ['A', 'B', 'C']
size = 40
matrices = {k:np.random.random([size,size]) for k in names}
```

I want to run some matrix algebra on each matrix, using the `multiprocessing` library's [`Pool.map`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.multiprocessing.Pool.map) which, according to the documention, is a parallel equivalent of the normal python `map` (so if I can do this with the built-in map, I can probably do it with `Pool.map` too...)

```
def hard_maths(matrix):
    return np.dot(np.linalg.inv(matrix),
            matrix).round(0)

pool = mp.Pool()
results = pool.map(hard_maths, matrices.itervalues())
pool.close()
pool.join()
```

This gets me my results as a `list`.

But how can I say which matrix (`A`, `B` or `C`) produced which result? In an ideal world, `results` would end up as a dictionary keyed with the same keys as `matrices` and with the values being the results.

*Note: I don't want to have to pass the entire `matrices` list to the function each time, as that creates a large data overhead which swamps the effects of the multiprocessing.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just pass the name with the value, then return both:

```
def hard_maths(name_matrix):
    name, matrix = name_matrix
    return name, np.dot(np.linalg.inv(matrix),
            matrix).round(0)

pool = mp.Pool()
results = pool.map(hard_maths, matrices.iteritems())
pool.close()
pool.join()
```

On linux, multiprocessing is implemented by forking. As long as the matrix exists when the pool is created, its already in the child process space and you can reduce overhead by just passing the name

```
def hard_maths(name):
    return name, np.dot(np.linalg.inv(matricies[name]),
            matrix).round(0)

pool = mp.Pool()
results = pool.map(hard_maths, matrices.iterkeys())
pool.close()
pool.join()
```

Comment: I think you'd need a starmap for that to work? can just unpack the argment into name and matrix in the function instead though. also as a guess, `dict(pool.map(hard_maths, matrices.iteritems()))` would get it into a keyed dict.

Comment: You can't use `map` like that. You'd need to use `starmap` if using Python 3.3+, or do `def hard_maths(name_matrix): name, matrix = name_matrix`

Comment: Wow! +1 for the Linux tip.